# I am auditioning for a role in Shrek. Which role is bigger? Fiona as a princess or Fiona as an ogre?

Tags: actors, shrek

I am auditioning for a role in *Shrek The Musical* and I want a big role.

**Which role is bigger (e.g. more stage-time): Fiona as a human, or Fiona as an ogress?**

Comment: The movie probably won't help if it's *Shrek: the Musical*.

Comment: Not sure why there are close votes saying "This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center." *Shrek: The Musical* is definitely in the fantasy genre.

Comment: I have removed the opinion-based portion of the question.

Answer (score 13):

There are three "Fiona" parts in [the script for Shrek the Musical](http://www.stagemanagement.com/vsm/public/message_upload/459000258/2440/Shrek%20script_1759.pdf); Young Fiona, Teen Fiona and Princess Fiona (who also plays the part of Ogress/Fiona wearing green makeup).

The part of Fiona is dramatically larger than that of her younger selves.

> **Young Fiona** = **52 lines in total** (The bulk of which are in one song at the start and 9 in the shared
>   song at the end).
>
> **Teen Fiona** = **40 lines in total** (The bulk of which are in one song at the start and 5 in the shared
>   song at the end).
>
> **Princess Fiona** = **408 lines in total** (138 lines in Act 1 + 270 lines in Act 2).

In the (unlikely) event that they've split off the role of Ogress/Fiona as a separate part, you should be aware that she only has 64 lines, over a third of which (23) are in the shared song at the end.

Comment: The question asked about "screen time" (implying that it was about the movie, not the musical) This answers a different question, about the number of lines in a play. I suggest you include information about the amount of "screen time" in the movie.

Comment: @JamesK - I did briefly consider it, but I decided that it's relatively unlikely that she'll be starring in the new live-action remake of the film

Comment: The amount of lines or screen time in *past* scripts need have little or nothing to do with that in *new* scripts.  It's common for characters to be sidelined or even killed off or for writers to deliberately focus on other or newer characters in films, particularly as a film series progresses.

Comment: @StephenG - I've looked at several versions of the show script. They haven't changed materially since v1.0.

Comment: Funnily enough, we're doing this one at one of the local theaters. My wife is playing the Fairy Godmother. I'm skipping it, myself, due to various commitments.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - "*Sorry, love. I'm busy that evening*". "***But I haven't told you which evening it is yet!***"

Comment: @Valorum ^_^ I plan to watch her in it, but I'm not acting. I started a new job recently.

Comment: @StephenG: A) This is a play, not a film or series of films.  B) Fiona is literally the female lead, so writing her out would imply a total rewrite of the story.